# Error: read ECONNRESET in request with Token in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I have a small API made in nodejs with express. A while ago I did not touch it and everything worked perfectly. Only now have I decided to implement JsonWebToken. In Postman, the login works fine, however, when trying to send the token as a header in a request I get an error. When i don't send the token in the request, response successfull (obviously since there is no token, the endpoint returns a 401 to me).

[image: 1]

If I try to do it after authenticating (saving the token in an environment variable) and this time assigning it to the header, the following happens
[image]

If I send anything if it works, apparently it has to do with the length of the token.

[image]

I have tried it outside of postman, and the same thing happens, so the error does not seem to be from postman.
I don't know how to solve the problem, apparently nodejs does not handle the request by the length of the token.Is there a way to expand that?

The nodejs server entry point is:

```js
// Enviroment process
require("dotenv").config();

// Body Parser
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

// Express server
const app = require("express")();

app.use(cors());

// BodyParser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes middleware
app.use(require("./routes/index"));

// Run server
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Escuchando en el puerto ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

Routes:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { checkToken } = require("../middlewares/authentication");

const app = express();

/// Base Routes
app.get(
  "/equipments",
 [checkToken],
  require("../controllers/equipment/get_all.controller")
);

module.exports = app;
```

The `checkToken` middleware:

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const checkToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.get("token") || req.query.token;
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SEED, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        ok: false,
        error: {
          message: "Invalid Token",
        },
      });
    }

    req.user = decoded.user;

    next();
  });
};

module.exports = {
  checkToken,
};
```

The `.env` variables:

```
// Node env (development | production)
NODE_ENV=development

// Server Port
PORT=3000

// Token Time Expiration
TOKEN_EXPIRES=48h

// Token Seed
SEED=exampleseed
```

**UPDATE**

When I send the token through the body of the request, the error does not occur, and everything works correctly (obviously changing the middleware so that it receives it by the body). The problem is when I send it by headers or a query parameter.

[image]

```js
const checkToken = (req, res, next) => {
  //   const token = req.get("token") || req.query.token;
  const token = req.body.token;
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SEED, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        ok: false,
        error: {
          message: "Invalid Token",
        },
      });
    }

    req.user = decoded.user;

    next();
  });
};
```

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION:**

After trying only those files, I realized that the error did not come from these. The problem was in the authentication. When creating the token I used the information of the logged in user, however, I had not realized that it had a base64 image field.

```js
// ... after login, user object contains object information
let token = jwt.sign(
        {
          user: {
            id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            image: user.image.base64Url
          },
        },
        process.env.SEED,
        { expiresIn: process.env.TOKEN_EXPIRES }
      );
```

The length of the base64 image made the token extremely long. Then when making the request and sending a string token with many characters, the reading error occurrs (Error: read ECONNRESET).
The solution was to ignore the image field when creating the token.

Finally, before an error of the same type, check that a field that contains too much information is not being sent.

Comment: whats the server side error?

Comment: could you put your code in your answer, it will help us to understand the structure of the API.

Comment: None occurs. If I send the real token, it is as if the request did not even get done. If you sent anything in as a token, everything is fine.

Comment: @gegs921 
I have added the code that executes said endpoint

Comment: @Ignacior is jwt.verify() asynchonous? try doing `console.log(token)` in your checkToken middleware. Say what the output was. (Inside the jwt.verify method)

Comment: If Is not a jwt from login auth,  print the token value. If not, doesn't  print anything

Comment: For example, the token value 'hello' Is printed. But it Is a true jwt nothing happens

Comment: Your middleware looks fine, maybe your error comes from `get_all.controller`, when your token is correct.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I found the solution, and yes, it was not in the code that I had submitted. I post the solution.